# sqlite not returning values selected from table not in other table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables whose relevant columns look more or less like the following:

```
table1.id:

zIXuJeY-qH
zJrcULGLXK
zXyIgnlylb
zZ7MYDGDAV
zbCFI4wKpe
ziGeauO-0O
zmzWbaGSb7

table2.id

zIXuJeY-qH
zIXuJeY-qH
zIXuJeY-qH
zIXuJeY-qH
zJrcULGLXK
zJrcULGLXK
```

in which table1.id is a primary key and table2.id is not a primary key. I'm trying to grab all the IDs from table 1 that are not in table 2, but am having trouble. If, for instance, I select a count of all the values that *are* in table two, I get:

```
>SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2);
>2
```

But if I try to find the IDs *not* in table2, I get 0:

```
>SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2);
>
```

There are 503 unique IDs in table1 and only 163 in table2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there can be nulls in `table2.id`?

```
NOT IN ( ..., null, ...)
```

does never result in `true` unfortunately (because - so the argumentation - null is the unknown value, and we cannot guarantee that the unknown value is not the value you are looking for obviously). A bad trap.

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2 where id is not null);
```

or an `EXISTS` clause instead.